# 'Sticky' navigation bar broken in Safari

Tags: jquery, navigation, sticky

I am trying to use this code to make a "sticky" navigation bar. When I looked at it in Safari it is broken (When I scroll down about 10px my browser jumps to the navigation bar which is ~350px down)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Calculate the height of <header>
    //Use outerHeight() instead of height() if have padding
    var aboveHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

//when scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        //if scrolled down more than the header’s height
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){

        // if yes, add “fixed” class to the <nav>
        // add padding top to the #content
            (value is same as the height of the nav)
            $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next()
            .css('padding-top','60px');

            } else {

        // when scroll up or less than aboveHeight,
            remove the “fixed” class, and the padding-top
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed').next()
            .css('padding-top','0');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you get if you log `$(window).scrollTop()` and `aboveHeight` to the console?

Comment: Also does this work in other browsers?